# How to manipulate HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I am trying to scale a HTML image on mouse over. The reason I am doing it in javascript is because I want to manipulate multiple elements in different ways by just hovering over one.
Here is my javascript(the element I am trying to manipulate is called "logoF"):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var logoF = document.getElementById("#logoF");

logoF.onmouseover=function(){
    logoF.style.webkitTransform= "scale(0.8)";
    logoF.style.msTransform= "scale(0.8)";
    logoF.style.transform= "scale(0.8)";
};

});
```

but for some reason it is not working. If anyone can tell me why it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You have to remove the `#` inside `var logoF = document.getElementById("#logoF");` . This is the right way -

```
var logoF = document.getElementById("logoF");
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var logoF = document.getElementById("logoF");

  logoF.onmouseover = function() {
    logoF.style.webkitTransform = "scale(0.8)";
    logoF.style.msTransform = "scale(0.8)";
    logoF.style.transform = "scale(0.8)";
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg" id="logoF" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Removed the "#" and itturns out I imported the script in the wrong place as well. Thanks for the help and nice <img> haha!

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong, that could be the problem.

Instead of

```
var logoF = document.getElementById("#logoF");
```

Try (without the "#")

```
var logoF = document.getElementById("logoF");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers:

```js
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '#logo', function(){
  $('img').toggleClass('scaled')
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}
#logo {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scaled {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
<img src="http://www.2fons.ru/pic/201406/1920x1080/2fons.ru-21593.jpg">
</div>
```